# Como guardar fingerprints en bd MySQL

Tags: python

estoy trabajando con la librería libfprint y pyfprint para toma de huellas dactilares, pero aún no he podido saber como guardarlas en bd de MySQL.
adjunto link GitHub del programa con el que estoy trabajando.
si alguien puede decirme como hacerlo, se lo agradecería.
https://github.com/luksan/pyfprint

Comment: Carlos no he usado nunca esa librería, la respuesta depende en gran medida de que objeto es una huella en python, como ese módulo representa una huella como objeto Python. No es lo mismo que sea una cadena, un array, una lista, un objeto propio de la librería, etc. Si el objeto es serializable una opción aunque no tiene por qué ser la más eficiente (y hay que tener ciertas pautas de seguridad para evitar la inyeccion de código Python malicioso) es usar cpickle o [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) para serializar el objeto y almacenarlo como una cadena UTF-8 en la bd.

Comment: Carlos, viendo muy por encima, veo que que dispones de un Objeto `Image` el cual es capaz de darte los bytes del bitmap que podrías eventualmente salvarlo como un BLOB en mysql, o como te comentó FJSevilla serializarlo con pickle. También dispones de un método `save_to_file` al que le pasas el path, de manera que podrías generar un `path`, salvar la imagen y por último guardar el primero en alguna columna de alguna tabla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus aportes. En otro blog me indicaron también que codificara la huella dactilar en formato base 64 para almacenarla en la bd y luego para verificarla tenía que cargarlas todas.
Pero apoyandome en los ejemplos enroll.py y verify.py no sé exactamente que variable tomar para guardar en formato base64 ni tampoco como cargarla para verificarla.

Comment: Estoy siguiendo la sugerencia de @FJSevilla  usando pickle pero estoy presentando el siguiente error. 
    TypeError: can't pickle SwigPyObject objects.
Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Carlos el objeto no es serializable debido a que hay tipos nativos de C y se usa SWIG para crear un wrapper entorno a las funciones y estructuras de la biblioteca `Fprint` de C. Viendo el código por encima, creo que el método `Fprint.data()` te debe retornar una cadena que puedes guardar y luego reconstruir el objeto pasándoselo al constructor de la clase `pyfprint.Fprint`. Es decir, si tienes una huella `huella.data()` debe retornar una cadena que puedes almacenar, luego deberías poder reconstruir la cadena con `huella = pyfprint.Fprint(cadena)`. Por desgracia no puedo testear nada.

Comment: FJSevilla quisiera hacerte una pregunta. Finalmente he podido resolver el problema de pyfprint pero ahora estoy tratando de integrarlo con mi proyecto en pyqt4 y MySQL y estoy teniendo un problema luego de enrolar las huellas "Violación de segmento (`core' generado)". Sabes a que se debe esto? ambos proyectos corren perfecto por separado pero al integrarlos tengo este problema y se cierra la aplicación.